# Editing a TextView from ListAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I have a ListView, which is backed by an ArrayAdapter. They are defined as such:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

list_item.xml contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp">
</TextView>
```

What I would like to do when adding an item to the list, is edit the TextView associated with the item, like changing it's colour for example. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the method `getView()` of your ArrayAdapter ([link to the reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)) for example:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item){
   public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
      View v = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
      TextView tx = (TextView) v;
      //do something with tx
      return v;
   }
};
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go watch this Google I/O talk: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html it explains the basics of ListView and how you would go about doing these sorts of things.